# Python Remote Debug Server not stopping at breakpoint when using Okteto with PyCharm

Tags: kubernetes, pycharm, fastapi, remote-debugging, okteto

### Overview

I am currently following [How to Develop and Debug Python Applications on Kubernetes](https://www.okteto.com/blog/how-to-develop-python-apps-in-kubernetes/) in order to debug a simple hello-world deployment using Okteto.

Everything *seems* to work but for some reason the debugger is not stopping at the breakpoint in PyCharm. The breakpoint is either ignored or never set. All I get is a warning after connecting to the debug server:

> pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /Users/sfalk/workspaces/okteto-example/src/service/router.py (will have no effect)

The biggest difference might be that I am using `FastAPI` instead of `Flask`.

### A Simple Hello-World Service

I've a slightly different setup, but essentially I am trying to debug this `router.py`, which is pretty much the same thing as the `app.py` (see [repository](https://github.com/okteto/python-getting-started)) from that tutorial I linked:

```py
import os
import socket

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

REMOTE_DEBUGGING = bool(os.environ.get("REMOTE_DEBUGGING", False))

app = FastAPI()


class Message(BaseModel):
    message: str


@app.get("/")
def hello_world():
    return Message(message=f"Hello {socket.gethostname()}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting server...")
    print(f"REMOTE_DEBUGGING: {REMOTE_DEBUGGING}")

    if REMOTE_DEBUGGING:
        import pydevd_pycharm

        print("Connecting to debugger...")
        print(f"pydevd-pycharm version: {pydevd_pycharm.VERSION_STRING}")
        pydevd_pycharm.settrace("0.0.0.0", port=9000, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)

    uvicorn.run(
        "service.router:app",
        port=8080,
        access_log=True,
        log_level="debug",
        reload=True,
        debug=True,
    )
```

### Okteto & Python Remote Debug Server

This here is my `okteto.yaml`:

```yaml
name: depl-router
command: bash
sync:
- .:/usr/src/app
forward:
- 8080:8080
reverse:
- 9000:9000
```

I have set up a run-configuration for the Python Remote Debug Server (PRDS) which has the following settings:

```
IDE host name: localhost
Port:          9000
```

After creating the Docker-image and having it deployed on the local Kubernetes cluster, I am using Docker Desktop on my local machine, I call `okteto up` and, for now, run the FastAPI server by hand as you can see in the log-output below. This is where we get the warning from the `pydev debugger`.

```
$ okteto up
 i  Using default @ docker-desktop as context
 ✓  Files synchronized
    Context:   docker-desktop
    Namespace: default
    Name:      depl-router
    Forward:   8080 -> 8080
    Reverse:   9000 <- 9000

root@depl-router-okteto-f49f5fc6-6gjxc:/usr/src/app# REMOTE_DEBUGGING=1 PYTHONPATH=src/. python src/service/router.py
Starting server...
REMOTE_DEBUGGING: True
Connecting to debugger...
pydevd-pycharm version: 213.6777.50
pydev debugger: warning: trying to add breakpoint to file that does not exist: /Users/sfalk/workspaces/okteto-example/src/service/router.py (will have no effect)
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [232] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [240]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

After connecting, this is what I am seeing in the PRDS:

```
Starting debug server at port 9,000
Use the following code to connect to the debugger:
import pydevd_pycharm
pydevd_pycharm.settrace('localhost', port=9000, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True, suspend=False)
Waiting for process connection…
Connected to pydev debugger (build 213.6777.50)
[32mINFO[0m:     Uvicorn running on [1mhttp://127.0.0.1:8080[0m (Press CTRL+C to quit)
[32mINFO[0m:     Started reloader process [[36m[1m152[0m] using [36m[1mstatreload[0m
```

### Sending HTTP-Requests & Reloading is Working

The good news is, that I am able to send a GET request and the deployed service is responding:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
{"message":"Hello depl-router-okteto-f49f5fc6-6gjxc"}
```

I am also able to modify the code locally and I can see that `Okteto` is correctly swapping modified files in the deployment/pod.

### Breakpoints Not Working

The main problem here is that setting a breakpoint does not work. This means that after setting a breakpoint and sending a GET request, PyCharm IDE and the PRDS do not respond at all. I'd expect a warning if the breakpoint could not have been set, but since there is no warning I assume that the breakpoint was either set, or there was never an attempt to do so.

After connecting to the PRDS, PyCharm telling my that the remote `router.py` file could not be mapped to it's local twin:

> Remote file `/usr/src/app/src/service/router.py` is mapped to the local path `./src/service/router.py` and can't be found. You can continue debugging, but without the source.

For this, I've tried to edit the RPDS configuration and set the mapping accordingly:

[image]

This is the directory which I am copying the repository to in my Docker image but we can also confirm this by looking at the run command for the FastAPI server which gets started from `/usr/src/app` (see the output after calling `okteto up`).

However, setting the path mapping has no effect. I can use the auto-detect option, which correctly identifies the local file, but it does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Stefan, would it be possible for you to post a sample repo that reproduced your issue?

I retested our python getting started guide today with the updated 2.0.2 cli, and breakpoints are getting hit in today's version of PyCharm Professional.

working branch `https://github.com/okteto/python-getting-started/tree/v2manifest`